# How to always display first row of a linear layout while scrolling through it in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-linearlayout

I am using a linearLayout *(Vertical)* inside a scrollView *(vertical)*. All children of linearLayout is of type TextView *(I am dynamically adding textViews in that linear layout)*.

I want to make the first row of the linearLayout to be always visible to the user but I don't know how to make this happen...

```
TextView textView;
textView.setText("First row");
        linearLayout2.addView(estimation);
```

After adding few more rows and while scrolling, I want "First row" displaying always to the user.

I'm designing the UI in such a way that needs the linearLayout scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time.
I can't take first row and put it outside the scrollView because scrollView is placed inside the horizontal scrollView so if I take that first row outside the scrollView the first row will not scroll horizontally.

Please help me...

Here is the xml file

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/addbtn_phase2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here inside the linearLayout, I'm adding textViews dynamically as I said before but **first row is not dynamically added.**

Comment: if it's inside a scrollview... then you need to move the first row _outside_ of the scroll view... unless you are familiar with handling views manually, and dealing with a bunch of other X/Y complexity and conversion of DPs, Pixels, PositionX/Y, etc.

Comment: No, I can't do that because scrollView is placed inside the horizontal scrollView so if I take that first row outside the scrollView the first row will not scroll horizontally. I'm designing the UI in such a way that needs the linearLayout scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time.

Comment: Can you include the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange the XML code as follows:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/addbtn_phase2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout3"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now add the first row in the relative layout.

**Importantly**, set the marginTop attribute for inner scrollView so that it won't overlap with contents of relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for something quite complex to achieve with discrete views/widgets.

Understand you cannot stop that view from scrolling because the view has no (direct) knowledge of this, it's being moved by the scrollview.

You could write a custom ScrollView that detects when some view (your TextView) reaches certain position in the screen (top), then proceed to "lift" the view outside of the ScrollView, appropriately place it in the exact same coordinates in screen, and then a coordinator will have to move it in sync with the horizontal ScrollView, so when that view moves, you translate that into a movement for the top view.

As you can see, things are getting complicated already.

You could just do the Horizontal Syncronization by keeping the Top TextView in its OWN Horizontal ScrollView (outside of the "main" ScrollView) and when the view scrolls horizontally, you "translate" this and replicate it programmatically in the "top horizontal" scroll view.

```
[Top Horizontal Scroll View]
   [Top TextView]

[Main ScrollView]
   [Scrollable Content minus the Top TextView]
```

So when you scroll MainScrollView... you also "manually move" the Top Horizontal one so it moves alongside.

Just an idea, but one that may have other issues.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks for giving such an idea. I added a relative layout inside the horizontal layout and put the first row in the relative layout and I set the marginTop to 20dp for the vertical scrollView. And it works... :) Thank You